# fat-free SELECT is not returning any data

Tags: php, fat-free-framework

i am using Fat-Free Framework to do rapid prototyping of my application. Now, whenever I try to load some data from database, i can use the `load()` function within the `SQL\Mapper` but it returned all of the column.

I found `SELECT()` function but it does not returning any data.

`$this->load(['myId=?',$id])` will return the data along with the other columns

`$this->select('name',['myId=?',$id])` should return the data from `name` column but i got nothing.

`$this->db->exec('SELECT name FROM persons WHERE myId=?',$id)` will return the the data from `name` column.

what is the proper way of using `SELECT()` from Fat-Free framework? my goal is to only retrieve single data from `name` column only.

Comment: https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/databases#SeekandYouShallFind

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to do it is like this:

```
$table = new DB\SQL\Mapper($db, 'persons');
// assign to $results
$results = $table->load(array('myId=?', $id));

foreach($results => $row){
  echo $row->name;
}
```

As described here: https://fatfreeframework.com/3.6/databases#SeekandYouShallFind